# How can I disallow all HTML using markdown (PHP and JS)?

Tags: php, javascript, html, markdown

I'm using the PHP markdown library: http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/ and the Javascript markdown library: http://attacklab.net/showdown/

I want to disallow all HTML, both the versions of markdown seem to allow it indiscriminately. My first attempt was simply to escape all html entities before feeding into markdown. However this also escapes the `<hyperlink>` and `<email>` syntax, which is very useful.

I'd like to escape all HTML (not remove) but preserve all markdown syntax.

Comment: Quick question: Why are you translating it in JavaScript as well as PHP? Wouldn't it make more sense, from a DRY perspective, to AJAX the translation? Just my 2c.

Comment: PHP handles all markdown conversion for pre-existing content. I use javascript to convert markdown on the fly when editing, just like SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options.

First, you can actually care about the HTML the user submits and do something about it.  Try [lib_filter](http://code.iamcal.com/php/lib_filter/) by Cal Henderson (of Flickr fame) or maybe something more heavyweight like [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).

Second, if you really only want to neutralize all HTML but keep special syntax, use [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) and then undo the conversions for the exact strings you're looking for with regexes.  That might be a teeny bit more hairy. ;)

Yes, these are both PHP implementations, not Javascript.  An ajax call to a special-purpose preview-generating script when the user stops typing for a moment should be speedy enough.  Or make them hit a button.

Comment: I considered the regex option, but matching URLs and email address with a regex is kind of icky.
I will check out HTMLPurifier, thanks.